# Access to remote included file classes and functions

Tags: php

```
<!-- php.ini -->
allow_url_include = On

<!-- fooFile.php on "http://www.example.com/" -->
<?php
  function fooFunc()
  { // this function has SOME SECURITY CODE that remote user can not be seen that...
    return ("this as fooFunc() on fooFile.php");
  }
?>

<!-- index.php on "my website" -->
<?php
  required_once("http://www.example.com/fooFile.php");
  echo fooFunc();
?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function fooFunc() in ...

Comment: Is the server at `example.com` configured to process PHP files or serve the raw source? You're probably getting the page already processed (thus containing no PHP code).

Comment: It seems it's better to use a web service...

Answer (score 2):

The server on example.com must return PHP as output. In other words, it must return plain text. Disable your PHP engine on example.com **or** change fooFile.php to :

```
<?php
echo <<<'EOD'
<?php
  function fooFunc()
  { return ("this as fooFunc() on fooFile.php");
  }
?>
EOD;
?>
```

Comment: fooFunc() function has SOME SECURITY CODE that remote user can not be seen that...

Comment: I'm sorry but if you want your remote user to execute your code, you must send it to him. You could try obfuscating your code but this would only offer a minimal protection.

Answer (score 1):

If you require a external php-page, you get the parsed results. Imagine what a security hazard it would be if you could "require" an external page and instantly see the code..

If you want to include it as source, the source should be readable, like making it a `.txt` in stead of a `.php`

Comment: fooFunc() function has SOME SECURITY CODE that remote user can not be seen that...

Comment: It is not possible to include PHP code from an external source without opening up your source for (at least) the server that is running this code. Otherwise you could try to present the result of that function in plain text and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make it plain text. If you don't want people to see the security info then store it somewhere else like an SQL or MySQL database, if your server supports it, then in the code you can just retrieve the data from your database.